# Perform NSRegularExpression action in a selected tableview cell

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nsregularexpression

I want to perform a `NSRegularExpression` action in a selected tableview cell. The problem is however, instead of preforming the action on the single selected item, it checks the entire array and then just blanks the answer "yes" on all items except websites (because of the separate "if" statements).

Here is the code:

```
NSArray *array = @"http://www.apple.com/, http://www.stackoverflow.com/, http://www.test.com/, This is text, 416-555-5555, 416-123-4567, This is also text.";
   //more code

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:sideSwipeCell];

    NSError *error = NULL;

    NSUInteger index = [buttons indexOfObject:button];
    NSDictionary* buttonInfo = [buttonData objectAtIndex:index];

    NSString *data = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"redirect_url"];

    NSRegularExpression *naNum = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSRange naNumMatch = [naNum rangeOfFirstMatchInString:data options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [data length])];

    if ([data rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound) {
        // do something.
    } else if ((!NSEqualRanges(naNumMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)))) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ignore the supplied indexPath, and create a new one? That is almost for sure your problem.

If its not add some log messages to the three cases and log the range, what was matched, and the indexPath.